# My Android Studio keeps crashing with RecyclerView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I'm not getting any errors, but every time I run my emulator my Android studio keeps crashing. I created the data class, the adapter and programmed the MainActivity and every thing looks fine.

What's causing it???

Here are my kt files:

BeverageAdapter.kt:

```
class BeverageAdapter(val drinkList:ArrayList<Beverage>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<BeverageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val textViewName2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.beer_text_view) as TextView



}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return drinkList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


    val user: Beverage = drinkList[position]



    holder.textViewName2.text = user.name





}

}
```

Beverage.kt:

```
data class Beverage(val name: String)
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.item_recycler_view)



    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))

    val users = ArrayList<Beverage> ()

    users.add(Beverage("Beer"))

    val adapter = BeverageAdapter(users)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you inflating wrong layout.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}
```

You inflating `R.layout.activity_main` but you need to inflate your `recycle_view_list_item` or how you named it but no an activity layout